# Logback for SOAP messages gets message text cut off

Tags: java, soap, logback, slf4j

I am trying to use logback to log SOAP messages. The SOAP messages can get rather large due to the complexity of the information exchanged. (which is out of my control).

My logback appender for the SOAP messages looks like this

```
  <appender name="SOAP"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <append>true</append>
    <File>${LogPath}/SOAPMessages.log</File>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{ISO8601} %X{requestID} %-5p [%c] - %m%n</pattern>
        <immediateFlush>${FileImmediateFlush}</immediateFlush>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <minIndex>${RollingFileMin}</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>${RollingFileMax}</maxIndex>
        <FileNamePattern>${LogPath}/${ApplicationName}.log.%i
        </FileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <MaxFileSize>${RollingFileSize}</MaxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
  </appender>
```

The problem I am having is that the larger SOAP messages get cut off.

How do I increase the message size or even better how do I disable a size limitation of a single message so it does not get cut off?

Note: I tried to research this, but anything that involves message sizes is referring to the total number of messages logback queues up. I don't care about that, I care about the size of the message.

Answer (score 0):

What application server do you use?

I had the same problem with Tomcat and adding the follow property's in  ***tomcat/bin/catalina.sh***, the problem was solved.

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS \
-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true \
-Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true \
-Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dumpTreshold=1000000 \
-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true \
-Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true \
```

If you use a different server, try to search for those property's to insert them in apropriated local in your server.

Comment: So you are saying that it's not logbacks fault but Tomcat's?

Comment: No, you can adding this property in your server to say for logback use these values if not it uses the default (i don't remember exactly how much, but is little).